# What's the best solution for OpenID with Django?

Tags: python, django, openid

**Please note**: this is an ancient question with ancient answers. Most of the linked apps are now unmaintained. These days, most people seem to use [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) or [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth). I'll leave the original question intact below for posterity's sake.

---

There are at least half a dozen Django apps that provide OpenID authentication for Django:

- [django-openid](http://github.com/simonw/django-openid)
- [django-openid-auth](https://launchpad.net/django-openid-auth)
- another [django-openid-auth](http://code.google.com/p/django-openid-auth/), which seems to be dead
- [django-authopenid](http://bitbucket.org/benoitc/django-authopenid/wiki/Home)
- [django-socialauth](http://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth) (which also provides authentication with Twitter and Facebook accounts)
- [django-socialregistration](http://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration) (has Facebook and Twitter authentication, too)
- [django-openid-consumer](http://code.google.com/p/django-openid-consumer/), a fork of Simon Willison's original django-openid. Seems more suited for simple blog comments than a full fledged registration workflow
- [django-social-auth](http://github.com/omab/django-social-auth)

I played around with a couple of them. Simon Willison's [django-openid](http://github.com/simonw/django-openid) made a good impression, but as he is at the forefront of trendsetting in Djangoland, I sometimes have difficulties wrapping my head around his trends (e.g. the whole dynamic urlpatterns system in django-openid). What's more, I couldn't get login to work with Google.

[django-authopenid](http://bitbucket.org/benoitc/django-authopenid/wiki/Home) made a good impression, and it seems to have good integration with [django-registration](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/wiki/Home). [django-socialauth](http://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth) and [django-socialregistration](http://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration) have support for Twitter and Facebook, which is definitely a plus. Who knows if and when Facebook will start to be an OpenID provider...? socialauth seems to have [its share of problems](http://www.elfsternberg.com/2009/11/24/django-socialauth-component-now-with-some-elfin-goodness/), though.

So, what is the best OpenID app out there? Please share any positive (and negative) experience. Thanks!

Comment: [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth#readme) by Matías Aguirre is another one, and it looks pretty active as a project as of today.

Apart from OpenId it supports all major providers (FB, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc.), supports user data population and multiple social accounts association to single users.

Comment: **Note:** django-social-auth has been renamed to [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth).

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The one that has proven to work best for me, and which seems most up-to-date is the one over at launchpad.

It integrated seamlessly with my application that already utilizes the django.auth module.

https://launchpad.net/django-openid-auth

To get a copy run:

```
bzr branch lp:django-openid-auth
```

Or install it via PyPI

```
pip install django-openid-auth
```

Comment: thank you! Is there any manual how to use it? I did not find it on launchpad.

Comment: There are some examples in the code repo http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~django-openid-auth/django-openid-auth/trunk/files along with an installation guide in the Readme.txt

Comment: it's on pypi -> pip install django-openid-auth

Comment: where i can find documentation

Comment: Unfortunately it's not compatible with django 1.5 - you'll get errors when rendering the templates

Comment: I also needed to do `pip install python-openid`

Comment: Is it compatible with Django 1.6?

Comment: Mostly everything is currently unmaintained, and from the research I just did, [Python Social Auth](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/) is the best option.

Answer (score 32):

The last post for this thread is in February. It's been almost 8 months and I'm pretty sure a lot of things have been changed.

I am very interested in Django-Socialauth since it supports gmail, yahoo, facebook, twitter, and OpenID.

I found two forks that seem up-to-date:

https://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth

https://github.com/agiliq/Django-Socialauth

The second fork has been recently updated at this moment.

I was wondering if anyone has recently used any of these forks? I am looking for the most reliable one for my website.

Thanks

*Update:* The most up-to-date fork appears to be [omab/django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth), which is also what [the pypi package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-social-auth) points at.

Comment: I've got it working using `pip install django-social-auth`, which looks to line up well with this fork: https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth. As a newbie, the most confusing thing was understanding how to align my login/error templates with the socialauth urls and views. The example site in the fork I mentioned helped a lot.

Comment: `django-social-auth` != `Django-Socialauth`, in fact, the first was created after hours of frustration with `Django-Socialauth`.

Comment: There is a newer fork at https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth

Comment: django-social-auth is now deprecated in favor of [omab/python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth)

Answer (score 12):

I prefer django-authopenid, but I think most of the mature solutions are pretty equal at this point. Still, it is what I see used the most. I've made a handful of customizations to how we use it without having to actually fork it, and that's a huge plus in my book. In other words, its fairly hookable.

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget [Elf Sternberg's fork](http://github.com/elfsternberg/Django-Socialauth) of django-socialauth - he's working to clean up what he sees as a lot of bad implementation decisions in the original socialauth app. Looks clean so far but it's unclear whether his project will have momentum.

Answer (score 5):

django-socialauth is good for me

Answer (score 2):

You could try [pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/)

Comment: Isn't that a bit too much? Though if he just needs openid, he can take a look on which one Pinax chose.