# which is the best openid Package of django 

Tags: django, authentication, openid

i want to build register/login(has openid) demo  uding django ,

i get many Packages via google  , like : https://github.com/simonw/django-openid

but  which is the The simplest Package ?

has the normal register/login and openid register/login

thanks

Comment: This is the question you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123369

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [djangopackages.com](http://djangopackages.com/), [authopenid](https://bitbucket.org/benoitc/django-authopenid/wiki/Home) seems like the most popular choice these days.