# easiest way to handle facebook/google login

Tags: django, openid

what is the easiest way to handle the logins from various openid providers in django ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[What's the best solution for OpenID with Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123369/whats-the-best-solution-for-openid-with-django)

The easiest in installation is  django-socialauth  ( facebook, openid, twitter etc. )

I preffer django-authopenid for openid and https://github.com/teebes/django-facebookconnect/
 for facebook.

Comment: Link changed to github example

Answer (score 0):

Try to install django-authopenid

Comment: i am not sure how it works , would it work with appengine also ?