# django-open-id: CSRF verification failed

Tags: python, django, django-csrf, django-openid-auth

I fallowed recommendation in this SO question: [What's the best solution for OpenID with Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123369/whats-the-best-solution-for-openid-with-django) and installed `django-openid-auth` for my application.

But I just can't get it working, I always get `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.` when I try to log in.

[image: django csrf]

I have checked everything:

## 1.

`{% csrf_token %}` is present in the template:

```
<form name="fopenid" action="{{ action }}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Sign In Using Your OpenID</legend>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="id_openid_identifier">OpenID:</label><br />
            {{ form.openid_identifier }}
        </div>
        <div class="submit-row ">
            <input name="bsignin" type="submit" value="Log in">
        </div>
 {% if next %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
 {% endif %}
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

## 2.

In the views.py inside of `django_openid_auth` I found, that they use `RequestContext`:

```
return render_to_response(template_name, {
                    'form': login_form,
                    redirect_field_name: redirect_to
                    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## 3.

My `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` does contain `CsrfViewMiddleware`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

I just can't understand what else could be wrong? Do you have any ideas?

I am using Django 1.3 beta.

## UPDATE

This seem to be my global problem. I've created a simple form and got the same result:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html',
                              locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

index.html:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="1fbd5345560d325bf05809260f7d43c3"></div>
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

What's wrong!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think it was the first bug I encountered in Django. I've updated my copy to fresh release of 1.3 and everything started working. Good job, Django developers!

Answer (score 1):

I tried "manage.py runserver localhost:8000" instead of "manage.py runserver" and it worked
my guess is it has some cookie problems because of ip in hostname
btw. i got this error with fresh copy of django 1.3