# OpenID for Django - current best options?

Tags: django, openid

Yes, I'm well aware of [OpenID with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123369/whats-the-best-solution-for-openid-with-django). And I also notice that the checked answer is **over 1.5 years old** - which is a lifetime on the internet. :) Not to mention that StackOverflow is now an [OpenID provider](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/), and that's gotta be a game-changer.

So what are the *current* recommended options for providing `OpenID` with Django?

Comment: According to [Questions with good but out-of-date answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73953/questions-with-once-good-answers-that-are-now-out-of-date-and-need-updates), it's not unreasonable to re-ask questions that are dated. If I'm wrong, oh well... not like I was using the karma for anything. :)

Comment: I'm using https://launchpad.net/django-openid-auth (from the checked answer) on some projects, and it works good. Also, seem to be more or less actively maintained.

Comment: @Anton, I guess that would be the not-dead version of `django-openid-auth`, then. :) Do you know if it works with StackOverflow's implementation of OpenID?

Comment: That I can't answer. Works OK with Google's, but I don't know if their implementation is similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem about 3 months ago (not exactly current but...) and found [Django-SocialRegistration](https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration) to be the best solution after many failed attempts. For me facebook authentication was also important, which social registration supports well.

Comment: Agree with this one. It is also well maintained package.